# Java QT Desktop Разработка

Tags: java, qt

Ребят, такой вопрос. Хочу по тренировать разработку десктопных приложений. Стандартные библиотеки мне не пришлись по вкусу. Решил использовать. QT? С ним можно разрабатывать десктопные приложения на Java? И если не сложно, поделитесь опытом и подеоитесь ресурсами. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы хотите создать десктопное приложение на Java?
А Swing пробовали?
Если уж все таки решили попробовать QT, то как вариант обертки на QT или использовать чистый QT а сообщение с Java делать через JNI.
**Ссылки:**

(Можно почитать как работает JNI на хабре)
JNI и C++ - https://habrahabr.ru/post/49660/ 
...
Больше не могу дать ссылок, не позволяет сервис. Надо > 10 баллов репутации :(

Comment: Все, можете больше ресурсов покидать :)

Comment: Если уж хотите поизвращаться, то JNI самое то. Ваш фронт-енд будет на QT, а внутренние механизмы будут обрабатываться на стороне Java. Но опять же, я понятия не имею что за приложения Вы решили делать и какой сложности.

Comment: Как вариант еще Swing. Делаете Java приложение и, к примеру, пакуете его в EXE при помощи Launch4j, если приложение под Windows. http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Я просто хотел сделать неплохое такое приложение ( именно десктопное ) и использовать Java, т.к. пока ее только и знаю ( основы ). Но стандартная библиотека Swing не очень-то для меня привлекательна. Хочу сделать UI-красивое приложение с анимацией и прочими фичами. Ну, значит придется еще и C++ подхватить. Как считаете?

Comment: Еще как вариант http://slick.ninjacave.com/ и https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/. Хоть это и библиотеки для разработки игр, но они на Java, а в libGDX к тому же есть готовые компоненты UI и довольно легко реализовать анимацию

Comment: Спасибо, гляну. Это движок не на андроид разве?

Comment: LibGDX? Desktop, Android, Web. Мультиплатформа :)